# How to pass multiple widgets in a GTK+ single button click event in C

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

So, I have many entries in a 2D array in my GTK application, like this:

```
GtkWidget *entries[10][10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                entries[i][j] = gtk_entry_new();
        }
}
```

And a button:

```
GtkWidget *btn;
btn = gtk_button_new_with_label("Calculate");
```

I want that, when the user clicks on the button, all the values in the entries be passed to the callback function in order to do some operations with the data.

I have:

`g_signal_connect(btn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(calculate), entries);`

And a function called calculate():

```
void calculate(GtkWidget *btn, gpointer data){
        double **values = (double **) data;
    
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                    printf("%f ", gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(values[i][j])));
                }
        
                printf("\n");
        }
}
```

Its name suggest that a calculation is going to be done. Indeed, I intend to develop the code to do so, but prior to it I need to get the data in the entries.

Why I am not successful in getting the data?

#### [UPDATE]

I changed `g_signal_connect(btn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(calculate), entries);` to `g_signal_connect(btn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(calculate), &entries[0][0]);`

The function calculate now is:

```
void calculate(GtkWidget* btn, gpointer *data){ 
    GtkWidget **values = (GtkWidget **) data;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            printf("%s\n", gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(*(values+i) + j)));
        }
    }
}
```

I was successul in getting the text of the first entry, using `gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(*values))`, but how can I get the texts of the other entries?

Comment: You are not passing a double pointer to `double` but a 2D array of pointers to `GtkEntry`. That is a completely different memory layout.

Comment: Also, what is the lifetime of `entries`? Is that a local variable in your function to initialized the widgets or is it some global variable?

Comment: The variables are always local. I have just updated my question right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messing up the type of parameter you pass to your callback function:

```c
GtkWidget *entries[10][10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                entries[i][j] = gtk_entry_new();
        }
}
...

g_signal_connect(btn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(calculate), entries);
```

This defines an array of 10*10 pointers.

But then you tell your compiler to treat it as a pointer to a pointer:

```c
void calculate(GtkWidget *btn, gpointer data){
        double **values = (double **) data;
```

This indicates a very different memory layout.
A 2D array is not the same as a pointer to pointer. Besides that your array contains pointers itself, not `double` values.

What you need is this:

```c
void calculate(GtkWidget *btn, gpointer data){
       GtkWidget*(*values)[10] = (GtkWidget*(*)[10])data;
...
```

This should fix your issue with addressing your entries properly.

Besides that you may run into another problem.
If the array `entries` is no longer valid at the time your callback function is called, you have an illegal memory access causing undefined behaviour.

You must make that array static or global. Or you must ensure that the function that did the initialization, never returns before the application is termianted.

Comment: This is what I meant in my comment about your code, but in much greater detail. I am not used to C, so I was a bit confused by which type you should have written in your callback.

Comment: How do I make the array static? `GtkWidget *entries[10][10];` becomes `static GtkWidget *entries[10][10];`?

Comment: Yes, that is one way. Or you can make it a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

### Solved in C++

I am not a but C Gtk+ user, but I was able to make it work under Gtkmm 3.24 (which I am more familiar with). Here is my program, which should be translatable to the C language:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <gtkmm.h>

class MainWindow : public Gtk::ApplicationWindow
{

public:

    MainWindow();

private:

    Gtk::Grid m_layout;

    Gtk::Button m_button;
    std::array<Gtk::Entry, 4> m_entries;

};

MainWindow::MainWindow()
: m_button{"Print entries content"}
{
    // Configuring entries:
    size_t count = 0u;
    for(auto& entry : m_entries)
    {
        entry.set_text("Entry #" + std::to_string(count));
        ++count;
    }

    // Configuring the button handler:
    m_button.signal_clicked().connect(
        [this]()
        {
            for(const auto& entry : m_entries)
            {
                std::cout << "Entry text : " << entry.get_text() << std::endl;
            }
        }
    );

    // Configuring window layout:
    m_layout.attach(m_entries[0], 0, 0, 1, 1);
    m_layout.attach(m_entries[1], 1, 0, 1, 1);
    m_layout.attach(m_entries[2], 0, 1, 1, 1);
    m_layout.attach(m_entries[3], 1, 1, 1, 1);
    m_layout.attach(m_button, 0, 2, 2, 1);

    // Adding the layout to the window:
    add(m_layout);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Gtk(mm) version : " << gtk_get_major_version() << "."
                                      << gtk_get_minor_version() << "."
                                      << gtk_get_micro_version() << std::endl;

    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.base");
  
    MainWindow window;
    window.show_all();
  
    return app->run(window);
}
```

By the way, note this is a (minimal) simplified version of what I have understood your problem to be.

### Other notes on your code snippets

Looking at your code, I see this line:

```c
double **values = (double **) data;
```

however, when you connect, you have:

```c
g_signal_connect(btn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(calculate), entries);
```

From what I understand from the `GtkButton` clicked signal handler, the type of `data` should match `entries`, which is a table of `GtkEntry`. Why, then cast it to `(double **)`?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I got now this error: cannot convert to a pointer type
printf("%f ", gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(values[i][j])));

This is because I changed now double **values = (double **) data to GtkWidget **values = (GtkWidget **) data.

Comment: I'll try to translate it in C when I have time.

Comment: What does `GtkEntry` instead of `double` do?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to look at it tonight.